# How to return a marshalled JSON that has a nested property?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, python-requests, rest

Fellow programmers from SO!

I am building a simple Spring Boot example just to add a Client using a RESTful API. I have written this Controller:

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/cliente")
public class ClienteController {
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Cliente add(@RequestParam(value = "nome", defaultValue = "") String nome, 
            @RequestParam(value = "logradouro", defaultValue = "") String logradouro,
            @RequestParam(value = "CEP", defaultValue = "") String CEP,
            @RequestParam(value = "bairro", defaultValue = "") String bairro,
            @RequestParam(value = "complemento", defaultValue = "") String complemento,
            @RequestParam(value = "municipio", defaultValue = "") String municipio,
            @RequestParam(value = "UF", defaultValue = "") String UF)
    {

        return new Cliente(nome,logradouro,complemento,bairro,municipio,UF,CEP);
    }
}
```

The `Cliente` class has an attribute which is an object from another class `Endereco`. Both classes are depicted below:

Cliente.java

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class Cliente {
    
    private UUID id;
    private String nome;
    private Endereco endereco;
    
    public Cliente(String nome,String logradouro,String complemento,
            String bairro, String municipio, String UF, String CEP) {
        this.id=UUID.randomUUID();
        this.nome=nome;
        this.endereco=new Endereco(logradouro,complemento,bairro,
                municipio,UF,CEP);
    }
}
```

Endereco.java

```
public class Endereco {
    
    private String logradouro;
    private String complemento;
    private String bairro;
    private String minicipio;
    private String UF;
    private String CEP;
    
    public Endereco(String logradouro, String complemento, String bairro, 
            String municipio, String UF, String CEP) {
        this.logradouro=logradouro;
        this.complemento=complemento;
        this.bairro=bairro;
        this.minicipio=municipio;
        this.UF=UF;
        this.CEP=CEP;
    }
    
}
```

Nevertheless, when I sent a `POST` request to the API (it is hosted on `localhost:8080` for testing purposes), the `JSON` does not return the `endereco` property. I supposed it should be a nested `JSON` object.
I am using Python requests to send this `POST` request:

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8080/api/cliente/add"

payload = {'nome': 'Fabio',
'logradouro': 'Rua dos Bobos',
'CEP': '66666-666',
'bairro': '',
'complemento': '',
'municipio': 'Belem',
'UF': 'PA'}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers={},
                            data = payload, files = [])

print(response.content)
```

The result shown does not include the `endereco` property:

> b'{"id":"84956a2b-2a29-435b-a19a-ea6093ab20a1","nome":"Fabio"}'

Is there anything silly that I'm missing?

Thanks for any clue.

Comment: How are you selecting the client when you add the endereco? An endereco belongs to a client, right?

Comment: Yes, an endereco (address in English) instance belongs to a client. Actually I am creating a cliente object and setting its endereco property to a new Endereco object.

Comment: Are you using Jackson?

Comment: Yes, this example I am taking from this guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ , where it is stated that Spring’s MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter is automatically chosen to convert the object instance.

Comment: While debugging do you see all the correct paraments being parsed to the attributes of `add` method in your Controller?

Answer (score 2):

first of all, the method in your controller is not ok.
the add method should accept a Cliente object with @RequestBody annotation.

and for your problem, you can use the @JsonUnwrapped which will unrapp the object either in serialization or deserialization.

in the end you will be with those classes :

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/cliente")
public class ClienteController {
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Cliente add(@RequestBody Cliente cliente)
    {

        // do whatever you want with the sent values
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class Cliente {
    
    private UUID id;
    private String nome;
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Endereco endereco;
    
    public Cliente(String nome,String logradouro,String complemento,
            String bairro, String municipio, String UF, String CEP) {
        this.id=UUID.randomUUID();
        this.nome=nome;
        this.endereco=new Endereco(logradouro,complemento,bairro,
                municipio,UF,CEP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Spring MVC, which I guess is your case, the annotation `@RequestParam` maps query parameters, form data, and parts in multipart requests.
In your case, you are sending JSON in the request body, which is not supported by `@RequestParam`.

This is the mapping of Spring annotation that handles the HTTP request header Content-Type:

- `@RequestParam` --> application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- `@RequestBody` --> application/json
- `@RequestPart` --> multipart/form-data

Having said that either the solution posted already by @Teyeb Med Malek, using DTOs that match your request body and are then converted to your model classes, or changing the body that you use in your request to be the following would work:

```json
{
  'nome': 'Fabio',
  'endereco': {
      'logradouro': 'Rua dos Bobos',
      'CEP': '66666-666',
      'bairro': '',
      'complemento': '',
      'municipio': 'Belem',
      'UF': 'PA'
  }
}
```